# cd to a directory doesn't work but ls does - why is this happening?

Tags: shell, cygwin

I started using [fish](https://fishshell.com/) today via Cygwin on Windows 10.

Whenever I execute

```
ls "G:/My Drive/"
```

I get a list of files and folders within that directory, which indicates that it can find the directory I am pointing `ls` to.

However, when I execute

```
cd "G:/My Drive/"
```

I get an error:

```
cd: The directory “G:/My Drive/” does not exist
```

I reinstalled Cygwin and also updated fish and it still behaves the same.

Why doesn't `cd` work?

Comment: I edited the tags: this is not fish specific, this is about the way that cygwin mounts the windows drives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered why this was happening; perhaps it can help others who experience the same problem.

It turns out that fish was mounted onto my drive, so instead of typing

```
cd "G:/My Drive/"
```

I have to type

```
cd /cygdrive/g/My\ Drive/dataSources/
```

**UPDATE (27th March 2019):**

I found [some documentation](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#cygdrive) that highlights this in more detail.